# Iterate plots through the group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df = 

         id_easy    latitude    longitude
level_0                 
0        6454       11          3
0        6454       12          4 
2        2323       23          5
2        2323       23          7
3        25603      13          5 
3        141        14          6
```

Want to plot:

- first plot: all `long` and `lat` values of `id_easy` `6454` in one color by showing the first points
- second plot: all `long` and `lat` values of `id_easy` `2323` in other color by showing the first points
- ...

same logic in the `len(df)`

My try:

```
for index_in_red in df.index.unique():
    plt.plot(df.loc[df.index != index_in_red,'longitude'],df.loc[df.index != index_in_red,'latitude'] ,
             color='silver', marker='o',linestyle='')

    plt.plot(df.loc[index_in_red,'longitude'],df.loc[index_in_red,'latitude']  ,
              color='maroon',marker='o',linestyle='')
    plt.show()
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "by showing the first points"?

Comment: @ScottBoston For example `id_easy` `6454` two couples of geo data. I want to show first couple special, to understand that trip started in that location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in df.index.unique():
    plt.plot(df[df['id_easy'] != i]['longitude'],df[df['id_easy'] != i]['latitude'] ,
         color='silver', marker='o',linestyle='')

    plt.plot(df[df['id_easy'] != i]['longitude'],df[df['id_easy'] != i]['latitude'] ,
         color='maroon',marker='o',linestyle='')
    plt.show()
```